# Unable to understand Python user defined functions

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I found this code somewhere in Google.i don't understand how the output is displayed in this sequence.can anyone explain me this?

Code:

```
def main():
    make_omelet()
    print("ocean")


def make_omelet():
    print("hello")
    break_eggs()
    print("sos")


def break_eggs():
    print("sea")


main()
```

Output:

```
hello
sea
sos
ocean
```

Comment: Try replacing any calls to a function by the functions contents. This should make the execution path clearer.

Comment: `main()` is executed: first, it calls `make_omelet()` —`main()` execution is paused here—;

`make_omelet()` is executed: first, it prints `"hello"`, then it calls `break_eggs()` —`make_omelet()` execution is paused here—;

`break_eggs()` is executed: it prints `"sea"`, then it returns (it returns `None` by default, since there is no explicit `return` statement, but that's not so important here);

`make_omelet()` is resumed and executes the next line: prints `"sos"` and returns (`None`);

`main()` is resumed and executes the next line: it prints `"ocean"` and returns (`None`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the flow that generates the output

main --> make_omelet  --> break_eggs

Follow the logic and see how the output is generated,